# openmpirun not found after port install openmpi, Mac OS Mavericks

Tags: macports, openmpi

I did installation of `openmpi` using `macports`:

```
sudo port install openmpi
```

I remember (vaguely) on another machine I could immediately use `openmpic++`. Now when I try `openmpic++` it says `command not found`

It's a completely clean machine. Nothing installed on it. I am doing this because I want to see how the installation procedure for a code on a clean machine works.

I don't have `XCode` installed, however everything got compiled using `macports` without problems. I have installed `mercurial` and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was very simple, should have known that:
`sudo port select --set mpi openmpi-devel-mp-fortran` or whatever `openmpi` is installed

Answer (score 0):

No compiler wrapper in Open MPI is called `ompi<whatever>`. The "standard" compiler wrappers are called `mpicc` (for C), `mpic++`/`mpiCC`/`mpicxx` (for C++), and `mpif77`/`mpif90`/`mpifort` (for Fortran). The OpenRTE component of Open MPI provides its own wrapper `ortecc` which is intended for compiling programs that make use of OpenRTE (not MPI programs).